# Sonar throws "failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar" in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube5.1.2

I have integrated Sonarqube with my Jenkins project as a post build activity. While running the build I'm getting "**failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli)**" error.

If I run "mvn sonar:sonar" via command prompt, The build is getting succeeded.
Has anyone faced this issue or can help me out with this.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXX: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/api/utils/SonarException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6

[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories
/1/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/2.6/sonar-maven-plugin-2.6.jar

[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar

[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar

[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar

[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar

[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar

[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar

[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar

[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar

[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-runner-api/2.4/sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar

[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar

[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar

[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/maven-repositories/1/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar

[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1

[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.XXXX.etl:XXXX:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Maybe providing the full error stacktrace might help you to get a proper answer.

Comment: @benzonico I have edited my post, please find the error log.